# Create a disable effect for a spinner

Tags: android, android-studio, android-spinner, effects

I am using a switch (on/off) to activate and deactivate some spinners, the thing is with the code I am using spinners don't show any effect or a dissable view, this is what I am doing:

```
spinner.getSelectedView();
spinner.setEnabled(false);
```

Is there something I could use to create a dissable effect for a spinner? thanks in advice.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,This may work for you.

```
((Spinner) spinner).getSelectedView().setEnabled(false);
spinner.setEnabled(false);
```

If the effect still not showing you can set it manually like this.(Some times `getSelectedView()` return `null` ).

```
private void setSpinnerState(Spinner spinner, boolean enabled) {
    spinner.setEnabled(enabled);
    spinner.setAlpha(enabled ? 1.0f : 0.4f);
}
```

And call the function like this.

```
setSpinnerState(spinner,spinnerstate);
```